# Diferença entre attr=val, attr="val" e attr='val' no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, seletores

Tem alguma diferença em utilizar o seletor das seguintes formas, ou alguma que é "correta"?

`[name="val"]` `[name='val']` `[name=val]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do ponto de vista do seletor, não há diferença, mas há umas considerações:

- Aspas simples ou duplas dependem de como começou o comando para não dar conflito. Exemplo:

`$('input[name="val"]')`  ou `$("input[name='val']")`

- Se o nome contiver caracteres especiais como `[]` por exemplo, o seletor precisará de aspas sempre, por exemplo:

`$("input[name='Campo[0].val']")`

- Nos outros casos, com um nome simples pode usar sem aspas:

`$('input[name=val]')`

```js
console.log($('input[name=val]').val());
console.log($('input[name="val"]').val());
console.log($("input[name='val']").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='val' value='teste' />
```

Comment: Se eu utilizar `[name=name]` pode em alguma hora ser um problema?

Comment: Não, ele vai sempre procurar um elemento onde a propriedade `name` seja "name". Agora, se seu código `js` pegar o nome dinamicamente, e você não sabe como virá (pode vir com caracteres como `$[]`, use aspas pra não ter surpresas.

Answer (score 3):

Uma boa prática é delimitar o valor do atributo selecionado por aspas duplas (`"valor"`) ou aspas simples (`'valor'`), dependendo de qual aspas foi utilizada no seletor.

Exemplos:

```
$("input[name='val']") // aspas duplas no seletor
$('input[name="val"]') // aspas simples no seletor
```

Embora a forma sem aspas possa funcionar em muitos casos, você pode omitir as aspas se o valor do atributo tiver apenas caracteres alfanuméricos (incluindo o hífen (`-`) e o *underscore* (`_`).

Exemplos:

```
<input name="val@" value="Enviar">
-> $("input[name=val@]").val()   // Retorno: erro! "@" não é alfanumérico
-> $("input[name='val@']").val() // Retorno: "Enviar"

<input name="val1 val2" value="Enviar">
-> $("input[name=val1 val2]").val()   // Retorno: erro! "espaço" não é alfanumérico
-> $("input[name='val1 val2']").val() // Retorno: "Enviar"
```

**Exemplos funcionais:**

Foi levantada nos comentários a questão do hífen e do *underscore*. Como dito, ambos caracteres fazem parte do grupo *alfanumérico*, portanto não ocorre erro se usados no seletor de atributo sem as aspas:

**Ex. 1 com aspas:**

```js
console.log($("input[name='-']").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="-" value="Enviar">
```

**Ex. 2 sem aspas:**

```js
console.log($("input[name=-]").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="-" value="Enviar">
```

### Edit

Também levantada nos comentários sobre uso do seletor em JavaScript puro, que há exceções no uso do hífen no nome do atributo sem o uso das aspas.

```
document.querySelector("input[name=-]") // ERRO!
document.querySelector("input[name=--]") // OK!
document.querySelector("input[name=-1]") // ERRO!
document.querySelector("input[name=--1]") // OK!
document.querySelector("input[name=-a]") // OK!
```

Comment: Não é verdade, não é questão de alfanumérico, o que vai ocasionar é um erro como `input[name=val@]' is not a valid selector`, tanto que poderia fazer isto `input[name=_-]` e vai retornar um ou mais inputs que sejam assim `<input name="_-">`, note que `[name=-]` falha acusando o mesmo erro que citei, mas `[name=_-]` funciona normalmente. Não é questão de alfanumérico, é questão de **sintaxe** mesmo e como ela trabalha, a questão é que muitos sinais podem confundir a sintaxe, então o interpretador não vai deixar passar qualquer coisa, e por isto existem delimitadores (como as aspas)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obg pela informação. Vou analisar aqui.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Acrescentei na resposta dois exemplos que contradizem o que vc disse.

Comment: *Não faça o teste com jQuery*, faça com JavaScript (`document.querySelector`), a pergunta é sobre seletores e JavaScript, frameworks simplesmente podem mudar o comportamento por algum motivo para facilitar ou por simplesmente os autores não terem pensado em repassar o problema, afinal de contas jQuery não é 100% querySelector, ele o usa, mas internamente, ou seja existem mais rotinas. --- Veja, esse é o resultado que rodei via console dentro do seu proprio Stacksnippet, sem mudar o HTML, somente executando um comando: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaBfJ.png

Answer (score 2):

Minha resposta é apenas para complementar as demais.

Caso você esteja utilizando os seletores do *Jquery* seria interessante seguir os padrões sugeridos do framework:

> **Aspas**
>
> *jQuery* utiliza aspas duplas.
>
> ```
> var double = "I am wrapped in double quotes";
> ```
>
> `Strings` que precisem de aspas internamente devem utilizar aspas
>   duplas fora e aspas simples dentro:
>
> ```
> var html = "<div id='my-id'></div>";
> ```

Fonte: [jquery.org](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#quotes)

Comment: Boa, e legal esse avatar do Urahara :)

Comment: Não concordo, uma que jQuery é apenas um framework, outra coisa que isto não tem haver com jQuery, seletores existem em independente do jQuery, a ideia do uso de aspas simples dentro sim é útil e concordo, o mesmo poderia ser feito ao contrário `'<div id="foo">'`, o que poderia até ser melhor, e no ES6 poderia até usar o *acento grave*. Não estou discordando da resposta, mas sim de como ela foi colocada.

Comment: Entendi seu ponto de vista, talvez eu tenha expressado mal. Eu sei que jquery é só um framework e da existência de seletores idependente dele, mas pelo que vi da pergunta ele estava utilizando os seletores do jQuery e minha intenção era apenas dizer que se você for utilizar um framework seria interessante seguir os padrões dele, apesar de que ele poderia estar utilizando um querySelector. Vou tentar mudar a resposta acho que ficou parecendo arbitrária ao invés de sugestiva.